# Probability of an event.

Tags: probability

Q.What is the probability that I will be alive on 2015/10/17?

Can I have a mathematical solution of the problem?

Attempt:
Let me try with.."Will I be alive 2 second larer?"

I will be alive 2 second later only if I am able to survive 1st second & 2nd second.

Each second have two possiblites but If I am dead at first second then I am unable to be alive on 2nd second.

Set of events:
(Alive,Alive),(Alive,Dead),(Dead,Dead)

That is:I have 33.33% chance of being alive at the 3rd second.

Do the same method can be applied to solve the question?

Comment: This is a typical question in actuarial science. Your current age, gender etc. is needed for this and then we can estimate the reqd. probability

Although (without doing any calculations), it'll come out to be very high like 99.999%

Comment: I have edited the question.Please have a  look.

Comment: do you believe that you have a 50% chance of dying in the next two seconds?

Comment: Mathematically,I may have 50% chance.

Comment: You forgot (Dead, Dead)!

Comment: It is not necessarily the case that all outcomes are equally likely.

Comment: There are many causes of death which are not instantly fatal. For example, your brain would need to be deprived of oxygen for a certain length of time in order for suffocation to take effect. Likewise, if you are healthy now it would take a virulent form of, say, cancer to kill you in 11 days. Your calculations would need account of daily risk patterns, e.g. higher at day if you travel long distances, less at night while sleeping. Exceptional events such as mountain climbing would also (ahem) elevate your risk. You cannot really apply Occam's razor second-to-second as seem to be suggesting.

Comment: But,while measuring the probability of a coin falling with head on..We dont care about torque,friction or windspeed...Therefore,here age,diseases..shouldnt matter.

Comment: u need to think of a better title. Literally every probability question can have that title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this comes up in studying how populations change over time. The only real way to estimate this is to collect data on the age of people when they die and construct the desired probability based on the outcomes of others. This is an example of experimental probability. This information is collected in various mortality tables. You can search the internet for examples of these

Once you have a mortality table that you like, you could create a probability distribution function via your favorite curve fitting technique. Once you have a p.d.f, then you can apply al the probability theory you are familiar with.

Another way of approaching this is through analyzing the [force of mortality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_of_mortality) to create a continuous p.d.f. that reflects you assumptions about how things change over time. Again this force of mortality will require using a mortality table of some kind on which you base your assumptions.